# Difference between dispatch_async and dispatch_sync on serial queue?

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I've created a serial queue like this:

```
    dispatch_queue_t _serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.name", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

What's the difference between `dispatch_async` called like this

```
 dispatch_async(_serialQueue, ^{ /* TASK 1 */ });
 dispatch_async(_serialQueue, ^{ /* TASK 2 */ });
```

And `dispatch_sync` called like this on this serial queue?

```
 dispatch_sync(_serialQueue, ^{ /* TASK 1 */ });
 dispatch_sync(_serialQueue, ^{ /* TASK 2 */ });
```

My understanding is that, regardless of which dispatch method is used, `TASK 1` will be executed and completed before `TASK 2`, correct?

Answer (score 425, accepted):

Yes. Using serial queue ensure the serial execution of tasks. The only difference is that `dispatch_sync` only return after the block is finished whereas `dispatch_async` return after it is added to the queue and may not finished.

for this code

```
dispatch_async(_serialQueue, ^{ printf("1"); });
printf("2");
dispatch_async(_serialQueue, ^{ printf("3"); });
printf("4");
```

It may print `2413` or `2143` or `1234` but `1` always before `3`

for this code

```
dispatch_sync(_serialQueue, ^{ printf("1"); });
printf("2");
dispatch_sync(_serialQueue, ^{ printf("3"); });
printf("4");
```

it always print `1234`

---

Note: For first code, it *won't* print `1324`. Because `printf("3")` is dispatched *after* `printf("2")` is executed. And a task can only be executed *after* it is dispatched.

---

The execution time of the tasks doesn't change anything. This code always print `12`

```
dispatch_async(_serialQueue, ^{ sleep(1000);printf("1"); });
dispatch_async(_serialQueue, ^{ printf("2"); });
```

What may happened is

- Thread 1: dispatch_async a time consuming task (task 1) to serial queue
- Thread 2: start executing task 1
- Thread 1: dispatch_async another task (task 2) to serial queue
- Thread 2: task 1 finished. start executing task 2
- Thread 2: task 2 finished.

and you always see `12`

Comment: it can also print 2134 and 1243

Comment: my question is why not we didn't do it like the normal way? `printf("1");printf("2") ;printf("3") ;printf("4")` - compared to `dispatch_sync`

Comment: @androniennn for second example? because some other thread may running `dispatch_sync(_serialQueue, ^{ /*change shared data*/ });` at same time.

Comment: @BryanChen would single-threaded application benefit from `dispatch_sync`?

Comment: @dig I don't think so. It is also likely to cause dead lock.

Comment: @MatteoGobbi u forgot 1324, not good when trying to be a besserwisser like that;)

Comment: @DevilInDisguise Why would it print 1324?

Comment: @somtingwong it probably wouldn't, but its possible

Comment: @DevilInDisguise Unless I'm mistaken `printf("2")` is always executed before `printf("3"). Its the first line of code hit when the first dispatch returns. Unless someone can explain otherwise, I'm positive 2 will print before 3

Comment: @somtingwong Good point indeed, I am trying to understand the dispatch, and so far I would agree that 2 will print before 3. If there is a chance for 3 to be printed before 2 please explain, I do not want to be confused at this point.

Comment: Let's say we were `dispatch_sync(_serialQueue, ^{ printf(timeConsuimingSomething); });` then `dispatch_sync(_serialQueue, ^{ printf(notTimeConsumingSomething); });`

Yet still `timeConsumingSomething` gets printed first right? How and what is it that is **holding** `notTimeConsumingSomething` from being printed first, **while** it's code is already finished before `timeConsumingSomething` !?

Comment: @asma22 Please note the difference between enqueue the task and execute the task. Because both `dispatch_sync` is called on a same thread, it is guarantee that both tasks will be enqueued with correct order. Then dispatch serial queue will ensure the tasks are executed with correct order.

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry meant **async** , I understand the `sync` situation
Let's say we were `dispatch_sync(_serialQueue, ^{ printf(timeConsuimingSomething); });` then `dispatch_sync(_serialQueue, ^{ printf(notTimeConsumingSomething); });` Yet still `timeConsumingSomething` gets printed first right? How and what is it that is **holding** `notTimeConsumingSomething` from being printed first, **while** it's code is already finished before `timeConsumingSomething` !?
*if possible can you please add a case where the passing elements have very different timing, like my question?

Comment: Super Thanks, I *think* I get it now. I just don't get what is the benefit/ use case of doing it this way or the other. I mean if the code is still to be executed in a serial way AND that no task would begin unless its previous task is finished then this is just like a serial queue performance-wise--Unless you are to compare this with something out of dispatchs effect similar to what you do did with **printf("2");** & **printf("4");**

Comment: @asma22 It is very useful to share a non-thread safe object between multiple threads/dispatch queues. If you only access the object in a serial queue, you know you are accessing it safely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108618/discussion-between-asma22-and-bryan-chen).

Comment: Shouldn't your first line be "Using serial queue ensure the serial **enqueueing** of tasks"?

Comment: @asma22 You can enqueue tasks to serial queue concurrently from multiple threads.

Comment: @BryanChen see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026043/concurrency-and-serial-queues-in-grand-central-dispatch) the whole point of an asynchronous dispatch is to **enqueue** the block and immediately return. If the block was enqueued on a serial queue, it may be many minutes before it is executed. Asynchronous dispatch specifically decouples enqueueing from execution. –

Comment: My Problem is I think your wording is incorrect. You should correct your first line to:  "Using serial queue ensure the serial **enqueueing** of tasks" . Serial queue ONLY ensures **serial enqueuing** if the task is `sync` then its waits for execution and if its `async` it doesn't wait for execution. You said **serial execution**, which isn't the case for async. The serial-ness of of a serial queue is about the tasks of the queue itself since its still concurrent to other queues.

Comment: I do mean __serial execution__. In point of view that all tasks are executed serial regards to other tasks in the same queue. Of cause it still can be concurrent regards to other queues. It is the whole point of GCD that tasks can be dispatched and executed concurrently.

Comment: Clean & Neat Explanation. Thanx for saving me from millions of time.

Comment: still learning and coming back to this post after 7 months... *It is very useful to share a non-thread safe object between multiple threads/dispatch queues. If you only access the object in a serial queue, you know you are accessing it safely* <-- access you only mean for write-read, otherwise read-read is non-problematic and good solution is to use `dispatch_barrier_async` as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28784770/5175709) right?

Comment: Yes access I mean read/write. The answer you linked is an optimization that similar to [readers-writer lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers–writer_lock). So if most of the operations are readonly, it will improve performance.

Answer (score 19):

The difference between `dispatch_sync` and `dispatch_async` is simple.

In both of your examples, `TASK 1` will always execute before `TASK 2` because it was dispatched before it.

In the `dispatch_sync` example, however, you won't dispatch `TASK 2` until after `TASK 1` has been dispatched *and executed*.  This is called ["blocking"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_%28computing%29).  Your code waits (or "blocks") until the task executes.

In the `dispatch_async` example, your code will not wait for execution to complete.  Both blocks will dispatch (and be enqueued) to the queue and the rest of your code will continue executing on that thread.  Then at some point in the future, (depending on what else has been dispatched to your queue), `Task 1` will execute and then `Task 2` will execute.

Comment: I think your get wrong order. first example is `async` which is the non-blocking version

Comment: I've edited your answer to *what I think you meant*. If this is not the case, please change it and clarify.

Comment: What if you call dispatch_sync and then dispatch_async on the same queue? (and vice versa)

Comment: On a serial queue, both tasks are still executed one after the other. In the first case, the caller waits for the first block to finish but doesn't wait for the second block. In the second case, the caller doesn't wait for the first block to finish, but waits for the second block. But since the queue executes the blocks in order, the caller effectively waits for both to finish.

Comment: A block could also do a dispatch_async on its own queue (adding further blocks which will be executed later); dispatch_sync on the own serial queue or main queue would deadlock. In this situation, the caller will wait for the original block to finish, but not for the other blocks. Just remember: dispatch_sync puts the block at the end of the queue, the queue executes code until that block is finished, and then dispatch_sync returns. dispatch_async just adds the block at the end of the queue.

Comment: what's the benefit of async dispatching/enqueueing if you still have to wait for execution to complete? Can you give a real use case for serial queue + async and serial queue + sync?

Comment: Another important behavior to consider in dispatch_sync, and dispatch_async on serial queues is nested asynchronous behavior from within them. For example, if you call an asynchronous method from a dispatch_sync or dispatch_async on a serial queue, how will the execution be transferred.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its now working like a charm.
Created a pull request for the source of the pod.

the last problem was this:
https://github.com/mickeyl/LTSupportAutomotive/pull/26/commits/03992d4652c11c9acfdaf4a11b99403657c6e6ee

Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

It is all related to main queue. There are 4 permutations.

i) Serial queue, dispatch async : Here the tasks will execute one after the other, but the main thread(effect on UI) will not wait for return

ii) Serial queue, dispatch sync: Here the tasks will execute one after the other, but the main thread(effect on UI) will show lag

iii) Concurrent queue, dispatch async : Here the tasks will execute in parallel and the main thread(effect on UI ) will not wait for return and will be smooth.

iv) Concurrent queue, dispatch sync : Here the tasks will execute in parallel, but the main thread(effect on UI) will show lag

Your choice of concurrent or serial queue depends on if you need an output from a previous task for the next one. If you depend on the previous task, adopt the serial queue else take concurrent queue.

And lastly this is a way of penetrating back to the main thread when we are done with our business :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
     // Do something here
}
```