# Get main queue block not getting executed on main thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, thread-safety, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I call `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),block())` and my `block()` fails to perform UI interactions, because it IS not getting called in main thread, why?

Note: I use [PSPDFUIKitMainThreadGuard](https://gist.github.com/steipete/5664345)

[image: Just a runtume illustration of the issue where a block named showListOfProviders() crash on setting a title of a UIViewController]

Comment: Just for curiosity: is there a particular reason for using `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW` instead of `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT`?

Comment: I use `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW` to perform server communication

Comment: I understand that, but why explicitly low instead of the default priority? :)

Comment: @JózsefVesza i made a macro a long time ago, and actually i don't remember why i used `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW ` instead of `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT `. Should i refactor it? Will be any advantage? Or is it just the way it should be? :) köszi

Comment: I'm not sure how it would affect your current situation, but unless you have a reason to use the low priority specifically, I think you should stick to the default queue. It will not block the UI, but has a high enough priority not to be preceded by too many other tasks.

Comment: Removed italics that may distract viewers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call UI modification blocks as `dispatch_sync()` on the main thread, as this, it can refresh UI without being blocked.

Comment: I always used `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` to execute on main thread without any issues before.

Comment: I always used `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` to execute my UI updates without any issues.  Main thread can be used in dispatch_async, but for UI update I advice you to use the sync version. Did you tried ?

Comment: Using dispatch_sync can easily result a deadlock, so thats why i use only dispatch_async, by the way the difference is:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19822753/1293167

Comment: It's a serial queue created on the fly. Not about updating the UI on the main queue... Again, have you tried my answer ?!

If you make a right conception, and be aware of you GCD flow, you won't have any deadlock

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this in Swift:

```
runThisInMainThread { () -> Void in
    // Run the method that crashes in here
}

func runThisInMainThread(block: dispatch_block_t) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
}
```

Its included as a standard function in my repo, check it out: https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually dispatching to the main thread, from the looks of your question, you are invoking your block and passing the return value of your block, e.g. `dispatch_async(queue, yourReturnValue);`

It should read:
`dispatch_async(queue, yourBlock);`
Not:
`dispatch_async(queue, yourBlock());`