# Serial queus and sync operations

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

im studying multithreading and what i want is some clarification on subject matter.

As far as i know, **SERIAL** queue execute tasks serially, are always executing one task at a time.

Now, **SYNCHRONOUS** function is a function, that returns only after all tasks complete.

Now, i'm a bit confused. What difference between those two?

if i understand correct, both of them will **block** current thread (if they are not "covered" in global concurrent queue), and both of them execute tasks exactly in FIFO order.

So, what exactly a difference between them? Yes, i understand that serial is a property of a queue, and sync is a function (or operation). But their functionality is like to be similiar.

Comment: I can add tasks to a serial queue without necessarily blocking my current thread.  Those tasks execute in order but without any implicit effect on the thread that submits the work.

Comment: @PhillipMills you mean, if we create a queue, that separate from main thread, and that queue would be serial and code will run separately from main thread?

Comment: Yes.  When you create a queue for background use, you can make it serial.  Then the code that uses it decides whether to wait for task completion or not.

Comment: @PhillipMills thank you for clarify :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing a queue with a function, so it is difficult to define "difference". Using a serial queue does guarantee sequential behaviour of its operations. Typically, you use a synchronous dispatch if your program has to wait for all queued operations to complete before your program completes. If every dispatch on a given queue is synchronous, then indeed there is no difference between using a queue or calling the operations.

However, here is a very useful case that shows the difference. Suppose operation A is lengthy and you do not want to block. Suppose operation B returns something computed by operation A, but it is called some arbitrary time later (like in response to a user action). You dispatch_async A onto the queue. Your program is not blocked. Sometime later, you need the result. You **dispatch_sync** operation B on the same serial queue.

Now if A is already complete, the queue is empty when you add B and B executes immediately. But (and here is the good part) if A is still executing (asynchronously), B is not dispatched until A is done, so your program is blocked until the result it needs is ready.

For more explanation of this, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822700/difference-between-dispatch-async-and-dispatch-sync-on-serial-queue).

The dangers of deadlock nicely handled for you by gcd.

Comment: thank you, but in your example why should we use dyspatch_sync, instead of get to main queue and proceed computation in it (when we got result from an operation A)?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question in this comment. In my answer, I am assuming the use of gcd (Grand Central Dispatch) for queue management and synchronous vs. asynchronous behaviour.